# Add to Array list a unique random object functionally

Tags: java, functional-programming, refactoring

```
public Hand dealHand(int endExclusive) {
        List<Card> randomCardsCreated = IntStream.range(0, endExclusive).
        mapToObj(i -> {
            Card randomCard = generateRandomCard();

            while (this.cardsDealt.contains(randomCard)) {
                randomCard = generateRandomCard();
            }
            return randomCard;
        }).
        collect(Collectors.toList());

        this.cardsDealt.addAll(randomCardsCreated);

        return Hand.hand(randomCardsCreated);
}
```

I have this method, it generates a random card and add it to a field list (cardsDealt). It also makes sure that the randomCard is not in the list, if it is it will generate a new random card. It will then create a list of x cards to add to the cardsDealt and It will then create a new Hand object that will contain the cardsDealt. I think it is self explanatory.

I would like to get rid of the mutability of randomCard, instead of changing randomCard i would like to do it functionally, but have not managed to get anything working so far.
I am also trying to get rid of the while loop and use streams.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

EDIT

Following the comments below, here is some more info.

Here is some more code in how the above is used.

```
public List<PlayerResult> playGame(Player... players) {
        List<Player> playersWithAHandOfCards = dealHandToAllPlayers(players);
        ...
}

private List<Player> dealHandToAllPlayers(Player[] players) {
        return Arrays.stream(players).map(this::dealHand).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Player dealHand(Player player) {
        Hand hand = deck.dealHand(5);
        return player(player.playerName, hand);
}
```

The code is at my github here https://github.com/hanfak/poker-game

EDIT 2:

I have rewritten the method in a procedural format and it looks good, took the advice of listing out all the cards, shuffling and selecting the first 5 cards as the hand and removing them from the deck.

More info. Rank and Suit are just enums, and Card class contains a constructor for Rank and Suit, and overridden equals and hashcode methods. Hand and Card are created using static factory methods.

```
private final List<Rank> ranks = Arrays.asList(Rank.values());
private final List<Suit> suits = Arrays.asList(Suit.values());
private List<Card> deck = createDeck();

public Hand dealHand(int endExclusive) {
        Collections.shuffle(deck);

        List<Card> dealtCards = getHand(endExclusive);

        deck = deck.stream()
            .filter(card -> !dealtCards.contains(card))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return Hand.hand(dealtCards);
    }

private List<Card> getHand(int endExclusive) {
        if(deck.size() >= 5) {
            return deck.subList(0, endExclusive);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not enough cards left over");
        }
    }

private List<Card> createDeck() {
        List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Rank rank : ranks) {
            for(Suit suit : suits) {
                deck.add(Card.card(rank, suit));
            }
        }
        return deck;
    }
```

I would still appreciate if this could be turned into a functional style, am not liking the use of Collections.shuffle(deck) and not being able to use final for the field 'deck'.

Comment: Does this code actually work as intended? Try this: start with an empty `cardsDealt`, and generate a list of 30 random cards. Set break pointer inside the `while` loop, and see if it ever gets hit (I would expect that it wouldn't be hit). Then examine the output, it is likely to contain some duplicates. This is because at the time you collect cards with `collect(Collectors.toList())` the `cardsDealt` collection is empty. It remains empty until after all random cards are generated, but the horse is out of the barn by then.

Comment: A simpler, faster, more correct way would be to create a list containing all cards except the ones already dealt, shuffle the list, and then take the first N ones. That's, BTW, exactly what you're doing when using real cards in real life.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes this is true, but the deal hand is used several times. So on the first run the cardsDealt array will be empty but on subsequent turns it will fill up.

Comment: The while loop is being hit, but it is not creating distinct cards in the hands. I need to fix this first

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use functional programming, you are almost there - you just need to consider a few small changes.

- In the stream you manufacture, instead of running `endExclusive` times by using Stream.range, how about you just `generate` an infinite stream and `limit` it to `EndExclusive`? It's an int, it's exactly the type of stuff for which the limit method was written.
- Instead of running in the while loop to make sure your random card is not in the dealt cards - how about using `filter` in the stream to do it natively?

In short, my code suggestion is:

```
public Hand dealHand(int endExclusive) {
    List<Card> randomCardsCreated = Stream.generate(()->generateRandomCard()).distinct().
    filter(i->!cardsDealt.contains(i)).limit(endExclusive).
    collect(Collectors.toList());

    this.cardsDealt.addAll(randomCardsCreated);

    return Hand.hand(randomCardsCreated);
}
```

`Stream.generate(()->generateRandomCard())` - generates an infinite stream of random cards.

`distinct()` filters any duplicate cards from the current hand (a problem not handled in the original code).

`filter(i->!cardsDealt.contains(i))` removes any card that's already dealt.

`limit(endExclusive)` limits the result to endExclusive cards in the hand.

Would that work for your implementation?

Comment: It still generates duplicates.

Comment: @JBNizet, duplicates within the hand, or duplicates with cards in the dealt deck?

Comment: duplicates in cardsDealt after the method has been called.

Comment: I imagine it's a result of a hand containing duplicate cards - that wasn't checked in the original code or in mine. I would add a second filter to the pipeline - distinctByKey; But without information on the Card class I have no idea by which key to filter. I added distinct() just to be on the safe side.

Comment: distinct() is sufficient. But still, this is a poor way of doing it, IMHO. It doesn't match the reality, is very slow by generating unaccepted random cards again and again, and will cause an infinite loop if there are not enough available cards.

Comment: I completely agree, but the question referred to "how to write the code in a functional way", and I was focused on maintaining the code structure the OP used. The same infinite loop potential exists in the OP implementation. The OP can handle the limited deck possibility by calling the dealHand only if more than endExclusive cards remain in the deck.

Comment: Sure. That's why I didn't downvote. The answer isn't wrong, per se, but incorrect functional code is as bad as incorrect non-functional code. The first thing to do is to make the code correct.

Comment: @Assafs this is a good way of thinking about it. See above for more info about the question. The Card clas overrides equals, and has two fields rank and suit. Thanks for a solution

Comment: @cani, did you implement my solution to replace your original while loop? If so, and if it helped your original question, would you consider an up-vote? I'm not sure I can help with the new, extended question.